# Using Amazon product api itemlookup to display the same price as on amazon website

Tags: amazon-product-api

For example,

```
require 'asin'
client = ASIN::Client.instance
@items = client.lookup '1119962595'
```

this ruby code using asin gem returns price $44.99, but looking up the item on the amazon.com website i get prices ranging from $15.65 to $20.37. I know this include shipping and all but is there a way to get the same price for single item as the one shown on the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add the `ResponseGroup` parameter:

```
@items = client.lookup '1119962595', ResponseGroup: :Offers
```